# Linux/Unix - how to enable one user to `sudo` without a password

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

How can a user be setup to `sudo` (or `su -`) without entering a password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You control sudo through the `sudoers` file. To edit this file, run `sudo visudo`.

I haven't tested this, but I think the following would allow all users in the "cdrom" group to run "sudo k3b" without needing a password:

```
%cdrom    ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/k3b
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=19236