# sudo keeps asking me for my password in fish shell

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo, ubuntu-11.04, fish

sudo in Ubuntu keeps asking me for my password for every command.  Previously, I only had to enter the password once, and then it would be remembered for a period of time.  This recently changed, probably after "upgrading" to Natty.

I've done `sudo visudo` and set `Defaults        env_reset, timestamp_timeout = 60`, tried rebooting, but it's still not working.  How do I fix this?

After suggestions below, my `/etc/sudoers` looks like this:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults:endolith timestamp_timeout=60

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**Update:**

I upgraded my VirtualBox and it started to suffer from the same problem.  At a guess, I ran bash, and tried to sudo in that, and the password is remembered correctly.  It's only when I use my default shell [fish](http://fishshell.com/) that it doesn't remember.  It did in the previous Ubuntu release, but no longer.

**Update:**

I upgraded to 13.05 and this magically started working again.  Now it asks for my password once, stops asking for a while, and then asks again after a period of time.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/148665/linux-unix-how-to-enable-one-user-to-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: @warren: That's not a duplicate.  I should be required to enter the password, but after I have entered it once, I don't have to for a given amount of time.  I have changed this amount of time with visudo in the past but it's not working anymore.

Comment: I think that you have to use multiple Defaults statements, rather than one common separated one.

Comment: @Stephanie, I am certain that having a single Defaults statement with comma separated values works fine.

Comment: i see you have added a line like `Defaults:endolith timestamp_timeout=60` , but you are not in any group called endolith, accordidng to another comment here.  so what username are you using?  Check with `whoami`, and add that username in place of `endolith` in `Defaults:endolith timestamp_timeout=60` or `endolith ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: @wim: yes, I'm in the right group, which I wrote as "username"

Comment: Group "username" is not mentioned in the file. Try adding `endolith ALL=(ALL) ALL` right under `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@endolith: Yes, it only seems to affect fish. I had the same problem, the issue is caused by the sudo option "tty_tickets". Disabling this on your /etc/sudoers file will solve the problem.

The following will disable tty_tickets:

```
Defaults        env_reset,!tty_tickets
```

Comment: Does this have any negative ramifications?

Comment: "Be careful if you offer SSH access to remote users, as you could unintentionally allow them to share elevated privileges with you if you disable tty_tickets." from http://ask.debian.net/questions/how-to-have-sudo-powers-shared-between-different-bash-sessions

Comment: I offer SSH access to a remote user, but it is only to myself, so I assume this does not cause any vulnerability?

Answer (score 5):

If nothing else works, try `sudo -i` (by itself). That'll give you a root shell after one password.

Comment: great point but slightly riskier than the request.

Comment: Considering this is the "Ubuntu way" for getting a rootshell, I figured it was a neat work around the problem. Every command is still logged.

Comment: It doesn't really fix the problem though, it is basically just a way to ignore it.

Comment: This is a workaround rather than a solution, but it's good and I don't mind if it automatically gives you half the bounty.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> I only had to enter the password once, and then it would be remembered for a period of time.

If I where to guess, I would bet that something about your `/var/run/sudo` directory is screwed up.  This directory is where the timestamp files are stored.  Maybe /var/run is full, maybe the permissions got screwed up.  Anyway, look at that directory, I suspect your problem may be there.

The permissions on my folder look like this.

```
# find /var/run/sudo/ -ls
1164242    4 drwx------   6 root     root         4096 Jan  1  1985 /var/run/sudo/
1179694    4 drwx------   2 root     www-data     4096 Jan  1  1985 /var/run/sudo/www-data
1164286    4 drwx------   2 root     myuser      4096 Jul 21 23:03 /var/run/sudo/myuser
1163399    0 -rw-------   1 root     myuser         0 Jul 13 22:42 /var/run/sudo/myuser/0
1163453    0 -rw-------   1 root     myuser         0 Jul 21 22:59 /var/run/sudo/myuser/2
1164309    0 -rw-------   1 root     myuser         0 Jul 21 23:03 /var/run/sudo/myuser/6
1163303    0 -rw-------   1 root     myuser         0 Jul 13 22:31 /var/run/sudo/myuser/5
```

For good measure you might also want to try running `sudo -K` to kill your current timestamp files.

Comment: `find: '/var/run/sudo': No such file or directory`

Comment: Well that is a bad sign, why not try creating it, and set the ownership/permissions like above.

Comment: Or you could just reinstall the package.

Comment: reinstalled sudo with synaptic and it still says that

Comment: I get the same thing on a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 10.10.  there is no `sudo` folder in `/var/run`.  In this virtual machine, it remembers my password as expected, so this doesn't seem relevant.  The only thing in visudo on this virtual machine is `Defaults env_reset`.  It also says `%sudo   ALL=(ALL) ALL` instead of `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the /etc/sudoers.d/ directory.

You can also try to downgrade the sudo package to the previous version.